# OCaml memory profiling with Memprof - TypeRex Utility

Tags: ocaml, typerex, memprof

My program uses all of available memory, so I wanted to check which functions and abstracts are spoiling my project. I decided to use Memprof, so I installed their compiler and compiled my code with command

```
ocamlfind ocamlopt -package xml-light unix.cmxa str.cmxa -c -g  NKJPxmlbasics.ml NKJP.mli NKJP.ml test.ml
```

and then run as suggested in tutorial

```
ocp-memprof --exec ./test
```

But there is error instead of result:

> Error: no memory profiling information found. Possible causes:
>   - the application was not compiled with memory profiling support;
>   - the application exited before any major garbage collection was performed.

I even managed once to make it work but I have no idea how it happened
http://memprof.typerex.org/users/97beffbaec332eb7b2a048b94f7a38cf/2015-12-15_17-33-50_ab17218e800fe0a68fc2cfa54c13bfa6_16194/index.html

Is there any way to use this tool properly in this situation? What am I missing?

Comment: What does `which ocamlopt` return ? Are you sure your executable's name is `test` ? Your application was running for a (long) moment before crashing with "Out of memory" ?

Comment: My app didn't crash but was taking about 3 GB before I managed to finally profile memory. I found that in one recursive function I misspelled variable and it caused memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

`ocamlfind ... -c ...` does not generate any executable. So, the `./test` that you are running was probably generated by a previous command, probably without the memprof switch.